# Compass in standard yeoman webapp setup not rendering linear-gradient properly

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, linear-gradients, grunt-contrib-compass

I have a vanilla webapp generated with `yo webapp` from [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), and I used the option to bring in Compass with SASS. My local Compass version is 0.12.2, currently the latest. Then, I put something like this in my `main.scss`, taken word for word from the [Compass gradients documentation](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/gradient/):

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient(left top, white, #dddddd));
```

However, this rendered in the CSS without any pre-processing on the linear-gradient function:

```
background-image(linear-gradient(left top, #ffffff, #dddddd));
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]:

What am I doing wrong that an example from the docs do not work?

Answer (score 0):

I dived into the source, namely in `lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/gradient_support.rb` and found a mixin function defined as `linear_gradient` with an underscore. I tried using the following in my SCSS and it worked:

```
@include background-image(linear_gradient(left top, white, #dddddd));
```

**EDIT:** Upon further inspection, this doesn't appear to work fully. It still produces an illegal `background-image: linear-gradient(left top, #ffffff, #dddddd);`.

Comment: Hyphens and dashes are interchangeable in Sass for functions, mixins, and variable names.  Some sort of legacy thing that wasn't worth dropping.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

Fresh install with Yeoman Webapp, followed the documentation about linear-gradients from Compass. I get the same result - **But note this**: Pre-processing IS happening, I think the reason we see no prefixes is because the most recent browsers (Including Chrome) do not require it.. apparently http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Unfortunately, it doesn't actually work without the prefix for me.